# Cookie se crea pero sólo la recuerda en la misma página

Tags: php

Estoy experimentando problemas a la hora de crear una cookie. Tengo una sección de noticias, y cuando alguien entra en cualquiera de estas noticias quiero que en función de si existe una cookie, mostrar o no un contenido.

A los usuarios que entran por primera vez en dos semanas (es el tiempo de expiración que tengo puesto), aparece una ventana emergente a los 20 segundos, y si el usuario pulsa cerrar, se debería crear la cookie, y lo hace...pero sólo para esa noticia en cuestión, si entro a otra la cookie no existe. Tengo lo siguiente:

```
<?php if (!isset($_COOKIE["leido_pop_up_sociales"])): ?>
  <div class="contenido_popup_sociales">

          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>

          <input type="checkbox" id="modal" value="value" onclick='ocultar_pop_sociales()'>
          <label id='btn-cerrar-sociales' for="modal">Cerrar</label>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Y esta es la función que crea la cookie. Estoy probando con dos:

```
function ocultar_pop_sociales() {
    $('.contenido_wrapper_sociales').hide();
    expires = new Date();

    expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + 1209600000);
    document.cookie = "leido_pop_up_sociales=Si;expires=" + expires.toUTCString(); //1º método
    setcookie('leido_pop_up_sociales', 'Si', expires.toUTCString(), "/"); //2º método
}
```

Estaba usando el primer método, pero el segundo, se supone que el tercer parámetro `"/"` es para que la cookie esté disponible en toda la página, que es lo que quiero, pero no ocurre eso. Sólo está disponible en la noticia en la que se cierra la ventana emergente.

Comment: Haz pensado usar localstorage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega el parametro :

```
path=<ruta>
```

Por defecto las cookies solo son validas en la página creada, sigue este ejemplo si quieres que se aplique a todo el sitio:

```
document.cookie = "nombrecookie=valorcookie; max-age=3600; path=/";
```

Puedes ver más detalles [aquí](https://cybmeta.com/cookies-en-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Por la razón que sea el segundo método, no me funciona, así que he optado por seguir con el 1º método. He conseguido que se la cookie esté disponible agregándole otro parámetro más, en este caso:

```
document.cookie = "leido_pop_up_sociales=Si;expires=" + expires.toUTCString() + "path=/";
```

Le he agregado / porque quiero que esté disponible en toda la web, pero se puede poner cualquier subdominio para que sólo esté disponible en esa sección.